# Delay between recorded commands in macro in PhpStorm

Tags: java, git, macros, phpstorm

I would like to make delay between command pull, commit and push in recorded macro, is it possible? No it executing to fast, the first one is not be able to finish before next is started. Maybe something like, make action only when previous was finished.

Comment: AFAIK there are no such settings -- macro functionality in PhpStorm is pretty simple (comparing to MS Office, for example).

Comment: Indeed there is no such option. Feel free to submit a feature request to http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA#newissue=yes .

Comment: Agreed.. Same problem. I think you should create a ticket here => [help desk](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/?phpstorm)

Comment: this has to be definitely my most awaited feature for Phpstorm.. i keep coming back to this again and again. hope there is a solution soon! Can you guys a recommend a hack to create artificial delays (like sending null keystrokes, etc) until a proper solution is created?

Comment: No need for the new issue, there it is, 8 years old already: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-124493 Please vote!